Understanding Intermediate Value - AES
I was studying the development of hamming weight models for an AES attack, and I was particularly confused by the python implementation of a Last Round Sub-Bytes attack.
The algorithm implemented in the code is as follows:
tmp = add_round_key(ciphertext) # Since XOR is reversible, this yields the intermediate value before the add_round_key operation in the final round.
tmp = inv_sbox(tmp)
How did we skip the ShiftRows operation entirely? I am assuming that in a reverse attack on AES, we will follow the same sequence--i.e., add_round_key, ShiftRows, inv_sbox.
Then why is it that this implementation ignores the ShiftRows implementation entirely?
P.S. I also saw a different attack position that was obtained as
tmp = xor(inv_sbox(add_round_key(ciphertext)), ShiftRows(ciphertext))
And I have no idea what point does this correspond to on the AES diagram.
Thanks
